# NSURLConnection with GCD inside NSOperationQueue, 1 connection at time

Tags: objective-c, upload, nsurlconnection, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

My app has to do a series of uploads, depending by user's actions. He can program a long list of uploads in a row, so I prefer that only one NSURLConnection is executed per time, to avoid network congestions. I'm using a NSOperationQueue to add the upload jobs; inside the queue I use:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:uploadRequest
                                   queue:tempQueue
                       completionHandler:/* completion code */];
```

My problem is that, even everything works, the function with the asynchronous connection returns immediately because the use of blocks, so the NSOperationQueue doesn't wait for the NSURLConnection to finish and it directly continues to the next upload.

I know I can implement -for example- a NSMutableArray to track the list of current and  pending uploads and dispatch them accordingly, but I'd like to know if there's a simple way to tell this loop to wait if there's already a opened NSURLConnection in progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a synchronous connection?

```
[myQueue addOperationWithBlock:^{
    NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:…
        returningResponse:… error:…];
    // …
}];
```

Then you set the maximum number of concurrent operations to 1 and the uploads should go one by one.

Comment: Can I do a synchronous connection in a background queue without blocking the UI? Is it possible to use sendSynchronousRequest with blocks, or I have to use delegate functions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The synchronous request blocks until it’s complete, but when you put it inside an operation queue, it doesn’t block the main thread. And because it blocks, it requires no delegate callbacks, you just receive everything from a single call. The only downside is that you don’t know the progress of a single request.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can set your operation queue maxConcurrentOperationCount to 1
Like [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1]
Hope this will work

Comment: I did, but the block function returns immediately, so it doesn't work because the queue seems to be cleared quickly.